# Highcharts graph width exceed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to make a graph fill the whole width of the parent div. When the page is loaded the width of the graph exceeds the width of the div.
I know there are similar topics targetting this problem, but I haven't find a working solution yet.

I have tried setting the width: 100% !important; on .highcharts-container but it just chops of the graph. I am using this bootstrap template: https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/sing-web-angular-dashboard-WB0J6BJ85

I think the problem has something to do with the sidebar. When the sidebar is full width, the chart exceeds the div, but when it is collapsed the chart fills up the div perfectly. When I open the console in chrome the chart resizes perfect.

Here are some pictures and the code of the chart and html.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEkyR.jpg

graph:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#bezoekers-graph').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <section class="widget">
                <header>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="fw-semi-bold">Aantal</span> bezoekers
                    </h4>
                    <div class="widget-controls">
                        <a href="#" data-widgster="close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <div class="widget-body">
                    <p class="fs-mini text-muted">
                        Aantal bezoekers voor <span class="fw-semi-bold">Kaffee vanGogh</span>.
                    </p>
                    <div id="bezoekers-graph">
                        <?php $this->load->view('templates/graphs/bezoekers-graph'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to use `overflow:hidden` on the graph?

Comment: Yes, it just hides the part of the graph that isn't in the div, but not the whole graph is visible.

Comment: Have you tried to set width:100% and float:left styles (in CSS) for #bezoekers-graph container ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work. But when I resize my window a little bit or I open the console in chrome, the graph is displayed perfectly. Is there maybe a javascript solution for this?

Comment: try to call chart.reflow(), Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow